# Different authentication for site users and admins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I need to separate regular users from administration users, as the regular users can use their email as login name and login via Facebook, Twitter and Google+, and admin users can only use a login name (instead of email address).

How can I do this using ASP.Net Identity 2.1?

Should I have two separate authentication databases? Or separate tables? Or is it possible with the same tables?